# How should global resources be declared in Terragrunt?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I need to create a single Azure Container Registry.  I'm using Terragrunt to manage several environments in Azure.  My simplified layout looks similar to this:

```
/modules
/environments
  /development
  /staging
  /production
```

The registry does not really fit in any of these environments since it is shared.  Is there a "best practices" way to create one-off global resources such as a container registry?  I could not come up with a way that I liked that didn't feel wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directory structure similar to the following:

```
account
├── _global
│   └── acr
├── dev
├── prod
└── stage
```

For each Azure account/subscription you have, create a top level `account` directory. Within that directory, at the top level, set up a `_global` folder for resources that are global to that account. Also create subdirectories for each environment.

Gruntwork's [example repo](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example) is a good reference.

Comment: Thanks, that example repo documents this very well.  It seems the code there does not demonstrate this exact scenario, but the important concept is putting global resources next to region- or environment-specific resources where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Not Azure specific, but have gone through a similar exercise, I assume there are global objects that associated with your account and not an environment.  This is the case in AWS with VPCs, instances etc, though items like IAM (user,role,role policy management) are owned by the account, so after a bit of trail and error I came up with the following at the same root as dev, staging, and prod....there are sub repositories of global mainly to keep down on the change scope.

All of the dev,stage,prod use the global directory through `terraform_remote_state`, actually `dependency` since i'm using `terragrunt`, but its analogous.

HTH

```
tree global
global
├── cloud_watch_alarm.tf
├── dynamo_db
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── iam
│   ├── iam_groups.tf
│   ├── iam_instance_profile.tf
│   ├── iam_policies.tf
│   ├── iam_policy_attachment.tf
│   ├── iam_role_policies.tf
│   ├── iam_roles.tf
│   ├── iam_user_group_membership.tf
│   ├── iam_users.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── provider.tf
│   ├── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
├── s3
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── provider.tf
│   ├── s3-ohio.tf
│   ├── s3.tf
│   └── terragrunt.hcl
├── sns_topic_subscription.tf
├── sns_topic.tf
├── sqs.tf
├── terragrunt.hcl
└── variables.tf
```

EDIT: Alas i can't state my practice is best, i asked the same question and got a similar answer